# Express as Meijer-G function

Tags: exponential-polynomials

I want to express $e^{x^2}$ as MeijerG function?

it would be possible? or what?

can i use $e^x$ MeijerG expression for this one?

Answer (score 2):

start from the [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG1/03/01/28/0001/)
$$G^{2,0}_{0,2}(z,\tfrac{1}{2}|b,c)=2z^{b+c}K_{c-b}(2z),$$
substitute $b=0$ and $c=1/2$,
$$G^{2,0}_{0,2}(z,\tfrac{1}{2}|0,\tfrac{1}{2})=2z^{1/2}K_{1/2}(2z)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2z},$$
and for $z=-x^2/2$ you have the desired relation.

Comment: thanks in advance. what is the reference book or article? would you guide me?

Comment: I gave a link to my reference.